# Bash Pipe Multiple Lines into Gnuplot

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have the code,

```
echo "set term postscript" |
echo "set output 'output.ps'" |
for FILE in output*; do
    echo "plot '${FILE}' u 1:2 w l t '1', '${FILE}' u 1:3 w l t '2', '${FILE}' u 1:4 w l t '3'"
done | gnuplot -persist
```

I want the first two lines to be printed before anything else inside gnuplot. How can I achieve this?

Best,

Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you are trying to "group" the first three commands and pipe their collective output into `gnuplot`? If so, you can write:

```
{
  echo "set term postscript"
  echo "set output 'output.ps'"
  for FILE in output* ; do
    echo "plot '${FILE}' u 1:2 w l t '1', '${FILE}' u 1:3 w l t '2', '${FILE}' u 1:4 w l t '3'"
  done
} | gnuplot -persist
```

**Edited to add:** Incidentally, you might find it more readable to break up your third `echo` across multiple lines:

```
    echo plot "'${FILE}' u 1:2 w l t '1'," \
              "'${FILE}' u 1:3 w l t '2'," \
              "'${FILE}' u 1:4 w l t '3'"
```

(`echo` joins its arguments with spaces, so this is equivalent to the previous. It's totally up to you which version you find easier to work with.)